# Rails routing error, because of controller def

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a Rails beginner and created a `def set_star` in the Controller, to change an attribute onclick.

```
class EbmsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @ebms = Ebm.all
  end

  def destroy
    @ebm = Ebm.find(params[:id])
    @ebm.destroy
    redirect_to categories_path
  end

  def create
    @ebm = Ebm.new(params[:ebm])
    @ebm.save
    redirect_to categories_path
  end

  def set_star
    @ebm = Ebm.find(params[:id])
    @ebm.write_attribute(:star, '1')
    redirect_to categories_path
  end
end
```

The button looks like this:

```
<% for ebm in @ebms do %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= ebm.number %></td>    
    <td><%= ebm.text %></td>
    <td><%= ebm.content %></td>
    <td><%= ebm.star %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Star', ebm, :method => :set_star, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

But somehow it wont work, when I click the button I always get a routing error:

```
 No route matches [POST] "/ebms/1"
```

In my routes, I simply defined:

```
 resources :ebms
```

So, I dont know what I did wrong! Thanks.

Comment: what is the route for set_star action ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `routes.rb` add the line

```
put 'ebms/:id/star', to: 'ebms#set_star', as: 'set_star'
```

Then change the `link_to` as follows

```
<%= link_to 'Star', set_star_path(ebm), method: :put, confirm: 'Are you sure?' %>
```

As Mattherick pointed out, also change your controller to `@ebm.update_attribute(:star, '1')`

Comment: that should work. but why are you using write_attribute instead of update_attribute?

Comment: Works thanks! @Mattherick i changed it to update_attribute after i got an error!(Beginner) Thanks